# Double integral with absolute function

Tags: calculus, integration, statistics, exponential-function, stochastic-integrals

If we have a double integral that
$$
\frac{1}{2\theta} \int_{x_2 - \theta}^{x_2 + \theta} \int_{x_1 - \theta}^{x_1 + \theta} \exp\Big(- \frac{|z_1 - z_2|}{\phi}\Big) dz_1dz_2,
$$
where $x_i, z_i \in\mathbb R$,
I think that it may be good to pass
$$
d = x_1 - x_2
$$
into the integral but I don't know how to deal with the lower and upper bound in double integral.

Comment: what is $d=x_1-x_2$? Are we changing variables? If so, then we should be changing the $z_i$.

Comment: @AlvinL I agree it should change the $z_i$.

Comment: Are you sure the variables for integration are exactly what you want?

Comment: @LaxmiNarayanBhandari Yes, I am sure.